# Android two latyout horizantally

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to put two layouts horizantally, small layout on the right and the big on on the left
i tried like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but still get the small one on the right, what should i do?

Comment: Isn't that what you said you wanted?

Comment: my code make the small one on the left , i need the small one on the right

Comment: Use weights to fulfill your requirement. Moreover it is preferred because of screen independence.

Comment: i don't know what is weights , would u give my an example on an answer please

Comment: @FernadoMargin check the solution I have posted. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Reference :**

[The use of layout_weight with Android layouts](http://www.chess-ix.com/2012/01/17/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/)

Thanks.

Comment: you always help me buddy, thanks a lot, i will accpet your answer, just a question: is your solution is independent ? i mean what ever the screen size is so the same percent will be ?

Comment: @FernadoMargin yes this is independent solution. You can run on any resolution it behaves same.

Comment: @FernadoMargin I added one reference link for better explanation with good examples.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for being late but i has problems with internet connection, and i already upvote to u , now i am upvoting to you but it seems that someone down vote,

Answer (score 1):

A LinearLayout displays its children in the order in which you add them: top to bottom = left to right, for a horizontal view and top to bottom for a vertical view.  Change the order of the views in the XML and they will change on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to see your comment lately. But try this:

**pseudo code(Untested):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightsum = "10"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
         >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#000000"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need to put orientation horizontal as it supports by default. Even there is no problem if you keep it as the other answerer said.